# How to show 12 hour format in Titanium IOS time picker

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

I read [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker-property-format24) but no result. My code is

```
Titanium.UI.createPicker({
    useSpinner : true,
    selectionIndicator : true,
    type : Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_TIME,
    value : defaultVal
});
```

I need the picker showing 12 hr format. `format24` property is there, for android only :(

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/152593/24-hour-clock-in-picker#comment-225272) I found that it is not possible to force IOS date settings to change. If date format of IOS is set to 24 hr format, the picker will show date/time in 24 hr and same for 12hr